How to make the test wait the thread pool task complete
When I using this Java code method to do a unit test:
package com.dolphin.client;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Slf4j
public class FeignClientApplication {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new MyTask(i));
        }
    }

    static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        private final int taskId;

        public MyTask(int taskId) {
            this.taskId = taskId;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Duration.ofHours(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("Task ID : " + taskId + " performed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

The test will automatically exit before the thread task complete. How to make the unit test wait the thread pool's task complete before exit?

Since JDK19 the easiest way is to use Autoclosable in try with resources:
try(ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)) {
    ...    
}

Prior to JDK19 use awaitTermination, or make use of the Future<?> returned from each submit call.
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Note that as you are running tests you should determine suitable values for length of time to wait, or add assertTimeout for specific tests. You could use the return value from awaitTermination to fail tests if they run for unexpectedly long period:
if (!executor.awaitTermination(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    fail("The tests took too long");


I did have some recollection that ExecutorService extends Autocloseable, but wasn't aware that a) this is only since JDK19 nor b) that it works for waiting for submitted tasks to be executed. I did look and it just calls awaitTermination under the hood, with a timeout of 1 day - so if you're not convinced your tasks will terminate, you might still want to call it yourself to shorten wait time.

You can use CountDownLatch.
@Slf4j
public class FeignClientApplication {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // wait for 10 "done" signals (number of tasks submitted)
        CountDownLatch allFinished = new CountDownLatch(10);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(new MyTask(i, allFinished));
        }
        allFinished.await();
    }

    static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        private final int taskId;
        private final CountDownLatch latch;

        public MyTask(int taskId, CountDownLatch l) {
            this.taskId = taskId;
            latch = l;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Duration.ofHours(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                // tell latch we're done
                latch.countDown();
            }
   
            System.out.println("Task ID : " + taskId + " performed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

If you don't want to add the latching into your task code, you can wrap it with a factory method
  static Runnable latched(Runnable wrapped, CountDownLatch latch) {
    return () -> {
      try {
        wrapped.run();
      } finally {
        latch.countDown();
      }
    };
  }

which would let you keep your existing MyTask code unchanged, and use the test code above but with executor.submit(latched(new MyTask(i), allFinished)) instead of executor.submit(new MyTask(i, allFinished)).

Java's Thread class has method join() which blocks until the thread finishes its task.
If you just do
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Duration.ofHours(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

you spawn a thread whose task is to pause for 1 hours, but once you spawn this thread you continue without it.
What you want is:
            try {
                Thread thread = new Thread( () -> { sleep(Duration.ofHours(1)); });
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

Code is based off of demos found of how to spawn a pool of threads ( https://github.com/ETERNALBLUEbullrun/javatests/blob/trunk/Demo.java ), but as your example just has one thread, have removed the pool.
New: Comment says want thread pool;
public class FeignClientApplication {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final int n = 10;
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[n];
        for(int x = 0; n > x; ++x) {
            try {
                final int threadIndex = x;
                threads[x] = new Thread(new MyTask(x));
                /*threads[x] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.printf("threads[%d].start.getId=%d", threadIndex, java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    }
                });*/
                threads[x].start();
//              threads[x] = new Thread( () -> {
//                  System.out.printf("threads[%i]", currentThread().getId());
//              });
                System.out.printf("threads[%d].getId=%d ", x, threads[x].getId());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.printf("E: threads[%d].start threw", x);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for(int x = n; 0 != x--; ) {
            long threadID = threads[x].getId();
            try {
                threads[x].join();
                System.out.printf(" %d->threads[%d] finishes", threadID, x);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("E: {%d}.join=InterruptedException");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

With Futures from ExecutorService
You can do pretty much the same thing by collecting all the futures you get from the submit() method:
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 futures.add(executor.submit(new MyTask(i)));
}
futures.forEach(future -> {
  try { 
    future.join(); 
  } catch (Exception x) {}
});


I want to use the thread pool, not one thread.

 public static void demoThread() {
  final int n = 8;
  Thread threads[] = new Thread[n];
  for(int i = 0; n > x; ++x) {
   try {
    final int threadIndex = x;
    threads[x] = new Thread(new DemoRunnable(x));
    threads[x].start();
    System.out.printf("threads[%d].getId=%d ", x, threads[x].getId());
   } catch (Exception ex) {
...
   }
  }
  for(int x = n; 0 != x--; ) {
   long threadID = threads[x].getId();
   try {
    threads[x].join();
    System.out.printf(" %d->threads[%d].join", threadID, x);
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
...
   }
  }
 }


Creating a Thread directly is pretty much obsolete at this point, and I believe what @Dolphin meant with "want to use thread pool" is "want to use ExecutorService". Which doesn't really invalidate your answer because the Future returned by submit() also has join(), so you could collect them into a list and then iterate like you do. I added a section for this.
